# How to periodically save matrixes within PARFOR loop?

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have been using a parallel loop (`Parfor`) in Matlab, and here is part of my code. (It is supposed to run a few days so I want to save my output periodically.

```
  parfor i = 1:N_boot

                      ...

           out1(i,:) = result1;
           out2(i,:) = result2;

       if mod(i,100) == 0
        % Here, I want to save out1 and out2 (export with .mat file) 

       end


  end
```

How can I save `out1` and `out2` for every 100th iteration?

(Saving workspace for every 100th iteration is also okay with me)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

uh, I don't know if that is supposed to exist. You would have to gather data from all workers. A quick workaround would be if you just wrap a normal `for` loop around the `parfor`:

```
stp = 100;
for j = 1:stp:N_boost/stp
   parfor i = j:stp

                      ...

           out1(i,:) = result1;
           out2(i,:) = result2;

       if mod(i,100) == 0
        % Here, I want to save out1 and out2 (export with .mat file) 

       end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to rewrite your code using `parfeval`, then you can call `fetchNext` to get the output. Keep in mind that fetchNext returns an index because results might not come in order. So basically call fetchNext 100 times, stitch the results together, save.

An alternative might be the use of an `parallel.pool.DataQueue` in your parfor loop, return the data via `send` and collect it with an `afterEach` callback.